# How to remove common value in excel under different rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have 2 columns.

The first column contains the account name of clients. If the clients purchased multiple products, there is no unique value. The client’s name will have multiple entry.

The second column contains the product they purchased. Say for example: computer, keyboard, mouse.

What is the formula in Excel in case I want to identify/remove all entries/clients who purchased a computer?

I need to have the data of those who only purchased either keyboard or mouse.

Example:
Column 1.    Column 2.
Mark.        Computer
Mark.        Keyboard
Mark.        Mouse
Louis.       Keyboard
Louis.       Mouse
Ryan.        Computer
Ryan.        Computer
Kenneth.     Computer
Herbert.     Keyboard
Nino.        Computer
Nino.        Mouse
Jason.       Mouse

In this scenario, Louis, Herbert, and Jason are the ones who did not purchase a computer.

I need assistance in creating a formula to identify quickly the 3 clients who did not purchase a computer. In real data, it involves thousands of clients which I cannot do manually.

Thank you.

Comment: Please update the question to include sample data and expected results. Ideally include your own attempt at solving your issue too.

Comment: So the desired result is simply the three names of persons that did not buy any computer?

Comment: Yes JvdV. I only need to find those names who did not buy any computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Excel ms365:**

As currently written, OP is looking to filter out the names of people that did not buy a single computer:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A13,COUNTIFS(A2:A13,A2:A13,B2:B13,"Computer")=0))
```

---

**PowerQuery:**

A nice alternative, for Excel 2016 for example, could be the use of PowerQuery:

[image]

Here the M-Code I used:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Filter = let l1=Table.Column(Source, "Person"), l2=Table.Column(Source, "Item") in List.Accumulate(List.Numbers(0, List.Count(l1)),List.Distinct(l1),(s,c)=> if l2{c}="Computer" then List.RemoveItems(s, {l1{c}}) else s)
in
    Filter
```

You can now load the result back to Excel. Whenever your dataset grows, you could update the query to reflect the new information in the output.

---

**Markdown Sample Data:**

| Person | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Computer |
| Mark | Keyboard |
| Mark | Mouse |
| Louis | Keyboard |
| Louis | Mouse |
| Ryan | Computer |
| Ryan | Computer |
| Kenneth | Computer |
| Herbert | Keyboard |
| Nino | Computer |
| Nino | Mouse |
| Jason | Mouse |

Comment: Thank you, JvdV. It seems unique function is not available in MS Office 2016 and lower.

Comment: @LouisKennethDorado you need to use this and remember to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. Enter formula in cell `E2` `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$13, MATCH(0, IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,$B$2:$B$13,"Computer")=0, COUNTIF($E$1:$E1, $A$2:$A$13), ""), 0)),"")`

Comment: Thank you, JvdV and Mayukh. Both formulas are working perfectly.

Comment: @LouisKennethDorado, great. If this has answered your question you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing cells is not possible, using a formula in Excel. However, I can tell you that you might need the `CountIF()` worksheet function in your solution, like in this example:

[image]